# Principal Curvature of a monkey saddle using ParametricPlot3D but graph is showing blank

Tags: plotting, differential-geometry

Edit: I'm working through a textbook by Alfred Gray, Modern Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces with Mathematica.

I'm trying to plot the principal curvature of a monkey saddle, which I've defined as:

```
monkeysaddle[u_, v_] := {u, v, u^3 - 3 u v^2}
```

Ive defined principal curvature as:

```
k1[x_][u_, v_] := mcurvature[x][u, v] +
   Sqrt[Simplify[mcurvature[x][u, v]^2 -
   gcurvature[x][u, v]]]

k2[x][u_, v_] := mcurvature[x][u, v] -
   Sqrt[Simplify[mcurvature[x][u, v]^2 -
   gcurvature[x][u, v]]]
```

When I run this code, it shows blank:

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{
   {r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta],
   k1[monkeysaddle ] [
   r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta]]},
   {r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta],
   k2[monkeysaddle] [
   r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta]]}}],
  {r, 0, 0.6}, {theta, 0, 3 Pi/2},
     PlotPoints -> {10, 30},
     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
     ViewPoint -> {1.5, -3.0, 0.6}]
```

my code for mcurvature (mean curvature) and gcurvature (Gauss curvature) work so I know the problem isn't there. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
ee[x_][u_, v_] := Simplify[D[x[uu, vv], uu].
D[x[uu, vv], uu]] /. {uu -> u, vv -> v}

ff[x_][u_, v_] := Simplify[D[x[uu, vv], uu].
D[x[uu, vv], vv]] /. {uu -> u, vv -> v}

gg[x_][u_, v_] := Simplify[D[x[uu, vv], vv]. 
D[x[uu, vv], vv]] /. {uu -> u, vv -> v}

eee[x_][u_, v_] := Simplify[Det[{
  D[x[uu, vv], uu, uu], D[x[uu, vv], uu], D[x[uu, vv], vv]}]/
  Sqrt[Simplify[D[x[uu, vv], uu]. D[x[uu, vv], uu] *
  D[x[uu, vv], vv].D[x[uu, vv], vv] -
  D[x[uu, vv], uu].
  D[x[uu, vv], vv]^2]]] /. {uu -> u, vv -> v}

fff[x_][u_, v_] := Simplify[Det[{
  D[x[uu, vv], uu, vv] D[x[uu, vv], uu] D[x[uu, vv], vv]}]/
  Sqrt[Simplify[D[x[uu, vv], uu].D[x[uu, vv], uu]*
  D[x[uu, vv], vv].D[x[uu, vv], vv] - 
  D[x[uu, vv], uu].
  D[x[uu, vv], vv]^2]]] /. {uu -> u, vv -> v}

ggg[x_][u_, v_] := Simplify[Det[{
  D[x[uu, vv], vv, vv] D[x[uu, vv], uu] D[x[uu, vv], vv]}]/
  Sqrt[Simplify[D[x[uu, vv], uu].D[x[uu, vv], uu]*
  D[x[uu, vv], vv].D[x[uu, vv], vv] - 
  D[x[uu, vv], uu].
  D[x[uu, vv], vv]^2]]] /. {uu -> u, vv -> v}

gcurvature[x_][u_, V_] := Simplify[
  (Det[{D[x[uu, vv], uu, uu], D[x[uu, vv], uu],
      D[x[uu, vv], vv]}]*
   Det[{D[x[uu, vv], vv, vv], D[x[uu, vv], uu],
      D[x[uu, vv], vv]}] -
   Det[{D[x[uu, vv], uu, vv], D[x[uu, vv], uu],
      D[x[uu, vv], vv]}]^2)/
  (D[x[uu, vv], uu].D[x[uu, vv], uu]*
      D[x[uu, vv], vv].D[x[uu, vv], vv] -
      D[x[uu, vv], uu].
      D[x[uu, vv], vv]^2)^2] /. {uu -> u, vv -> v}

mcurvature[x_][u_, v_] := Simplify[
 (Det[{D[x[uu, vv], uu, uu], D[x[uu, vv], uu],
     D[x[uu, vv] , vv]}]*
     D[x[uu, vv] , vv].D[x[uu, vv] , vv] -
  2 Det[{D[x[uu, vv], uu , vv], D[x[uu, vv] , uu],
     D[x[uu, vv] , vv]}]*
     D[x[uu, vv] , uu].D[x[uu, vv] , vv] +
  Det[{D[x[uu, vv] , vv, vv], D[x[uu, vv] , uu],
     D[x[uu, vv] , vv]}]*
     D[x[uu, vv] , uu].D[x[uu, vv] , uu])/
 (2 (D[x[uu, vv] , uu].D[x[uu, vv] , uu]*
     D[x[uu, vv] , vv].D[x[uu, vv] , vv] -
     D[x[uu, vv] , uu].
     D[x[uu, vv] , vv]^2)^(3/2))] /. {uu -> u, vv -> v}
```

NOTE: Code for Gauss curvature and mean curvature are based off of these formulas:[image]

Also, thanks for pointing out my neglectfulness. I wasn't intentionally trying to pass code off as my own. Lesson learned!

Comment: Can you provide your `mcurvature` and `gcurvature`? People are most likely to help when they can just paste your code and play with it. On the other hand I think your issue is just that you need to use `x_` instead of `x` in `k2[x][u_, v_] := ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the OP has been neglectful in mentioning that the routines `gcurvature` and `mcurvature` were obtained from the [*Mathematica* notebooks](http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/abbena/gray/) associated with the book *[Modern Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces with Mathematica](https://www.crcpress.com/Modern-Differential-Geometry-of-Curves-and-Surfaces-with-Mathematica-Third/Abbena-Salamon-Gray/p/book/9781584884484)*. Here are the required definitions (which I modified slightly):

```
gcurvature[x_][u_, v_] := Block[{uu, vv},
      (Det[{D[x[uu, vv], uu, uu], D[x[uu, vv], uu], D[x[uu, vv], vv]}] 
       Det[{D[x[uu, vv], vv, vv], D[x[uu, vv], uu], D[x[uu, vv], vv]}] - 
       Det[{D[x[uu, vv], uu, vv], D[x[uu, vv], uu], D[x[uu, vv], vv]}]^2)/
      (D[x[uu, vv], uu].D[x[uu, vv], uu] D[x[uu, vv], vv].D[x[uu, vv], vv] -
       (D[x[uu, vv], uu].D[x[uu, vv], vv])^2)^2 /. {uu -> u, vv -> v}]

mcurvature[x_][u_, v_] := Block[{uu, vv},
      (Det[{D[x[uu, vv], uu, uu], D[x[uu, vv], uu], D[x[uu, vv], vv]}]
       D[x[uu, vv], vv].D[x[uu, vv], vv] - 
       2 Det[{D[x[uu, vv], uu, vv], D[x[uu, vv], uu], D[x[uu, vv], vv]}]
       D[x[uu, vv], uu].D[x[uu, vv], vv] +
       Det[{D[x[uu, vv], vv, vv], D[x[uu, vv], uu], D[x[uu, vv], vv]}]
       D[x[uu, vv], uu].D[x[uu, vv], uu])/
      (2 (D[x[uu, vv], uu].D[x[uu, vv], uu] D[x[uu, vv], vv].D[x[uu, vv], vv] -
       (D[x[uu, vv], uu].D[x[uu, vv], vv])^2)^(3/2)) /. {uu -> u, vv -> v}]
```

Note the use of dummy variables, so that the differentiation can proceed before numerical values of `u` and `v` are passed to the curvature routines. Rewriting your principal curvature routines in a similar style, we have

```
k1[x_][u_, v_] := Block[{uu, vv}, mcurvature[x][uu, vv] +
   Sqrt[Simplify[mcurvature[x][uu, vv]^2 - gcurvature[x][uu, vv]]] /. {uu -> u, vv -> v}]

k2[x_][u_, v_] := Block[{uu, vv}, mcurvature[x][uu, vv] - 
   Sqrt[Simplify[mcurvature[x][uu, vv]^2 - gcurvature[x][uu, vv]]] /. {uu -> u, vv -> v}]
```

Then:

```
monkeysaddle[u_, v_] := {u, v, u^3 - 3 u v^2}

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], k1[monkeysaddle][r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ]]},
                           {r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], k2[monkeysaddle][r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ]]}}],
                 {r, 0, 0.6}, {θ, 0, 3 π/2}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
                 PlotPoints -> {10, 30}, ViewPoint -> {1.5, -3.0, 0.6}]
```

[image: principal curvatures of a monkey saddle]